# RDS MySQL DNS hostname incorrect

Tags: mysql, dns, amazon-rds, rdbms

I am trying to connect to my RDS MySQL instance using MySql client on a ubuntu terminal. When I type the following command and provide it the database password, I notice that it fails and it seems like it is trying to connect to a different hostname than the one I want it to connect to. What am I missing?

Desired DB Host: `iraas.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

Seems to be trying to connect to: `pool-101-8-58-129.nwrknj.fios.verizon.net`

```
mysql \
--host=iraas.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
--port=3306 \
--user=my-user -p blahblah

Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my-user'@'pool-101-8-58-119.nwrknj.fios.verizon.net' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: pool-101-8-58-129.nwrknj.fios.verizon.net is the host name of the client computer, not the server. Your computer does not have access to your server.

Comment: @Shadow - yes, that's my client computer.. but don't know why mysql client is not taking the hostname i am passing in the `-h` option..

Comment: Then perhaps you should study the mysql manual on access control... The host name part of the user id stands for the client, not the server.

Comment: @Shadow -- from mysql Man page, mysql "--host" says "Connect to the MySQL server on the given host." and the iraas.* is in fact my mysql host name. What am I missing?

Comment: Please read the answer to the duplicate question.